# SQL Server database restore to same pc

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to restore sql server database bak file to same server but with different name. When i run restore original database starts showing restoring. I have changed old database Logical Name and new database .mdf and .ldf files location.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the Databases folder (not any of the databases) and select Restore Database.

General Pane:
Under Destination for Restore, To Database, give it a name.
Under Source for Restore, go pick the .bak file you want.  Make sure it's checked for Restore.

Options Pane:
Check that the paths in Restore As are correct with the name you want.

Click OK to restore.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DB2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DB1.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'<database name>' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DB2.mdf',  MOVE N'<database name>_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DB2_1.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

The 'database name' would be filled in with the friendly name of the original db you're restoring.  For example, 'Adventure Works'.